# When creating a Sharepoint survey, how can I have an automatically self-updating dropdown list of answers choices?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, survey-list, survey

I am working with SharePoint and creating a survey with it. I would need to have a question where the choices for answers update automatically based on an outside source (either excel or SharePoint List).

The survey is to act as a feedback form for a reporting platform. As such, we want the user to start filling the survey by specifying which report he is evaluating using a dropdown list. Since we are creating new reports quite often, I would like that this dropdown list automatically updates itself every time a new report is created.

We would maintain an excel or SharePoint list with the names of the reports (based on what is easier to link to the SharePoint survey).

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by creating a question of type "Lookup" and creating a list of reports in SharePoint (custom list). Using a lookup column you have to option to add or update reports in your reports list. All changes made to your list are directly visible in your survey.

Comment: Dear Suleyman,Thanks a lot for your help. Would it be possible to also do something similar with an excel file and javascript rather than Workpoint? I'm afraid that people will be more enclined to keep the excel up to date rather than the SharePoint list... Thanks!

Comment: There is no OOB way for creating a lookup based on an Excel sheet that I know of. I also never done something like this with javascript. If it's an issue to keep the list of reports up te date you could just use a choice field with current report names and enable the option to specify others so the user who is respoding can fill in the report name. You will end up with a lot of report names spelled differently but that can be fixed later manually in excel.

Comment: Hi Suleyman, Thanks again.

Can you advise on how I can proceed with SharePoint lists?
I understand how to create a list and link it to the survey.

However, what can I do if for instance, I want the user to 1. Choose the workbook from the dropdown list
and then 2. choose a sheet within this workbook.

Do I need to do 2 lists? I would like that once for example, the user chooses Wokrbook 1, the dropdown list for Sheets only shows him the sheets from Workbook 1.